# Motorcycle information? Ryoko Hakubi I think,

Tags: tenchi-multiverse

[image: Tenchi Muyo motorcycle]

So I printed off this picture probably almost a decade ago, can't remember where I found it and can't find it again. My question is this: I'm interested in the bike, does it actually exist, or is it fan art? If it does exist, can you tell me what episode or issue is from?

I *think* it's Ryoko Hakubi from Tenchi Muyo, but I know nothing about that series. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks, senshin. I didn't think about formatting ;-) Additional info, I came across this in some gallery that I think consisted of animated characters and their motorcycles. No real info at that time.

Comment: We'll help you identify the source of the image in question, but I identifying the bike is off-topic. This is a fan-colored version of the Vol. 6, chapter 3 title page if the Tenchi Muyo manga BTW.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because    it's about identifying a motorbike.